# how to post image in react-redux using formdata and send to nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am new in react and  I don,t have seen any documentation regarding image uploading using formdata (react) and also i can,t send image on server(nodejs).if anyone of u have something then send it here like mern stack image uploading

Answer (score 0):

Check out my git repository with image uploading react frontend and node.js server to upload images to AWS S3 bucket. https://github.com/ShanikaEdiriweera/image-upload-app

As an addition to @Nguyễn Thanh Tú answer and the method used in repo (calling http request from react component), this is how you should use Redux and action creators ([redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) as middleware) for handling side effects like API/server calls.

**Component code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as imageActions from '../actions/imageActions';
export default class WhatsApp extends Component {
    ...

    handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!this.fileInput.current.files[0]) return;
        let data = new FormData();
        data.append('logo', this.fileInput.current.files[0]);

        // calling the action creator
        this.props.imageActions.imageUpload(data);
    };

    ...
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        imageActions: bindActionCreators(imageActions, dispatch),
        ...
    };
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(WhatsApp);
```

**imageActions.js actions file:**

```
import axios from 'axios';
...
export const imageUpload = (data) => {
    return dispatch => {
        return axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:3100/what', data).then(
            // here we can dispatch redux actions
            // and then handle them in redux reducers
            res => console.log(res.data),
            err => console.log(err.message)
        );
    };
};
```

Inside action creator, we can dispatch [redux actions](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions) and then handle the dispatched actions in [redux reducers](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers) to create effects back on the frontend components.

Answer (score 0):

if you are with react with hooks and redux this is the way that i used and works.

The trick is to use **formData.set()**, i used before, formData.append and not works, to send the values of the states of the fields of your form to the axios.post(i use axios.create).

It's not necessary to configure headers if you don't need to use user authentication.

It's importat!!!, the image field, will be **type='file'**, and in the state use **e.target.files[0]**,

**in the formComponent:**

```
//* AQUI ESTARÁ EL FORMULARIO PARA EL PRODUCTO
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import FormData from "form-data";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

//ACTIONS DE REDUX
import { crearNuevoProductoAction } from "../actions/productoActions";


const Label = styled.label`
  font-family: Anton;
`;

const TextArea = styled.textarea`
  font-family: Lato;
`;

const tablas = [
  { value: "slalom", label: "Slalom" },
  { value: "freeride", label: "Free-Ride" },
  { value: "freerace", label: "Free-Race" },
  { value: "freestyle", label: "Free-Style" },
  { value: "waves", label: "Waves" },
];

const velas = [
  { value: "slalom", label: "Slalom_V" },
  { value: "freeride", label: "Free-Ride" },
  { value: "freerace", label: "Free-Race" },
  { value: "freestyle", label: "Free-Style" },
  { value: "waves", label: "Waves" },
];

const botavaras = [
  { value: "carbono", label: "Carbono" },
  { value: "aluminio", label: "Aluminio" },
  { value: "mixtas", label: "Mixtas" },
];

const mastiles = [
  { value: "rdm", label: "RDM" },
  { value: "sdm", label: "SDM" },
];

const accesorios = [
  { value: "arnes", label: "Arnes" },
  { value: "alargador", label: "Alargador" },
  { value: "aleta", label: "Aleta" },
];

const NuevoProducto = () => {
  //MANEJO DE STATES LOCALES
  const [categoria, setCategoria] = useState("");

  const handleProduct = (e) => {
    setCategoria(e.target.value);
  };

  const [subCategoria, setSubCategoria] = useState("");

  const handleSubProduct = (e) => {
    setSubCategoria(e.value);
  };

  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [images, setImage] = useState("");
  
  console.log(images)

  let subopcion;

  switch (categoria) {
    case "tabla":
      subopcion = tablas;
      break;

    case "vela":
      subopcion = velas;
      break;

    case "botavara":
      subopcion = botavaras;
      break;

    case "mastil":
      subopcion = mastiles;
      break;

    case "accesorio":
      subopcion = accesorios;
      break;

    default:
      subopcion = tablas;
      break;
  }

  //MANEJO DEL REDUX EN EL FORMULARIO

  //UTILIZAR USEDISPATCH Y TE CREA UNA FUNCION
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  //manda llamar al action de productoAction
  const agregarProducto = (producto) =>
    dispatch(crearNuevoProductoAction(producto));

  //AL HACER SUBMIT EN EL FORMULARIO
  
  
  const submitNuevoProducto = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.set('images', images)
    formData.set('title', title)
    formData.set('categoria', categoria)
    formData.set('subCategoria', subCategoria)
    formData.set('price', price)
    formData.set('description', description)

     agregarProducto(formData)
  
  };

  return (
    <div className="container mt-5">
      <div className="row justify-content-center">
        <div className="col-md-8">
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-body">
              <h2 className="text-center mx-auto font-wight-bold mb-5">
                Agregar Nuevo Producto
              </h2>
              <form onSubmit={submitNuevoProducto}>
                <div className="mb-3">
                  <Label className="mb-2">Selecciona el tipo de producto</Label>
                  <select
                    className="custom-select form-control"
                    defaultValue=""
                    name="categoria"
                    onChange={handleProduct}
                  >
                    <option value="" selected>
                      Selecciona el tipo de producto
                    </option>
                    <option value="tabla">Tabla</option>
                    <option value="vela">Vela</option>
                    <option value="botavara">Botavara</option>
                    <option value="mastil">Mastil</option>
                    <option value="accesorio">Accesorio</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3">
                  <Label className="mb-2">Selecciona el tipo de producto</Label>
                  <Select
                    defaultValue=""
                    name="subCategoria"
                    onChange={handleSubProduct}
                    options={subopcion}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3">
                  <Label htmlFor="tituloProducto" className="form-label">
                    Producto
                  </Label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    name="title"
                    id="title"
                    placeholder="Tabla Slalom ...."
                    onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
                  ></input>
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3">
                  <Label htmlFor="precioProducto" className="form-label">
                    Precio
                  </Label>
                  <input
                    type="number"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="precioProducto"
                    placeholder="450"
                    name="price"
                    onChange={(e) => setPrice(Number(e.target.value))}
                  ></input>
                 
                </div>

                <div className="mb-3">
                  <Label htmlFor="descripcionProducto" className="form-label">
                    Descripción del Producto
                  </Label>
                  <TextArea
                    className="form-control"
                    id="descripcionProducto"
                    rows="3"
                    onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
                  ></TextArea>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <input
                    className="form-input"
                    id="images"
                    type='file'
                    name="images"                                      
                    onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.files[0])}
                  ></input>
                   
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3 text-center">
                  <button className="btn btn-success" type="submit">
                    Agregar Producto
                  </button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NuevoProducto;
```

**in the actions.js**

```
import clienteAxios from "../config/axios";

import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import FormData from "form-data";


const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
const data = ({
  
  headers: {
    'x-auth-token': user,
  },
  //body: {imagenData},
  
})

console.log(user)
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//CREAR NUEVOS PRODUCTOS
export function crearNuevoProductoAction(producto) {
  console.log(producto)
  return async (dispatch) => {   
    dispatch(agregarProducto());
    try {
      //INSERTAR EN LA API
       await clienteAxios.post("/api/productos", producto, data);
      //console.log(respuestaPost.data);
      //SI TODO VA BIEN, SE ACTUALIZA EL STATE
      dispatch(agregarProductoExito(producto));     
      //PONER AQUÍ LA ALERTA DE QUE SE CREO BIEN EL PRODUCTO
      Swal.fire(
        'Correcto',
        'El Producto se subió Correctamente',
        'success'
      ).then(function() {
        window.location = "/productos"})
      
      console.log(producto)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      dispatch(agregarProductoError(true));
    }
  };
}

  const agregarProducto = () => ({
  type: AGREGAR_PRODUCTO,
  payload: true,
 });

 //SI EL PRODUCTO SE GUARDA EN LA BBDD
  const agregarProductoExito = (producto) => ({
  type: AGREGAR_PRODUCTO_EXITO,
  payload: producto,
  });

  //SI HUBO UN ERROR CON EL PRODUCTO
  const agregarProductoError = (estado) => ({
  type: AGREGAR_PRODUCTO_ERROR,
  payload: estado,
   });
```