# How to upload an image in React with expressjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux, sequelize.js

I triying to upload an image with formidable in React with express for save the image path into database .I readed these tutorials: [sequelize crud with expressjs](https://grokonez.com/node-js/sequelize-orm-build-crud-restapis-with-nodejs-express-sequelize-mysql)
 and [Simple File Upload with Express.js and Formidable in Node.js](http://shiya.io/simple-file-upload-with-express-js-and-formidable-in-node-js/)
the trouble that I have is that I can't mixed for upload images from React and save the URL into database.

I have this in my React Code for set the State:

```
picture(e){
    this.setState({
        picture:e.target.files[0]
    });
    console.log(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

Into my render() method I just handle it :

```
<input type="file" onChange={this.picture} className="form-control-file" placeholder="Picture" name="picture"/>
```

Into my controller I have this code:

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {    
    // Save to MySQL database
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    var fileName;
    form.parse(req);
    form.on('fileBegin', function (name, file){
        fileName='/home/public_html/react-panel/img/' + file.name;
        file.path = '/home/public_html/react-panel/img/' + file.name;
        console.log('fileBegin ' + fileName);
    });
    form.on('file', function (name, file){
        console.log('Uploaded ' + file.name);
    });
    StrongDish.create({  
            id: req.body.id,
            name: req.body.name,
            description: req.body.description,
            picture: fileName,
            category: req.body.category,
            price: req.body.price
    }).then(strongDish => {     
        // Send created customer to client
        res.send(strongDish);
    });
};
```

The other data keep save in the database except the ima file

For make the post I just call an action with redux sending the data of the state

```
export const addStrongDish=dish=>async dispatch=>{
    const response = await axios.post('http://www.my-domain.co.cr/api/dish/add/',dish);
    dispatch({
        type:ADD_DISH,
        payload:response.data
    })
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed this issue replacing formidable with [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

Answer (score 0):

From react form is better to use formData, this allow you to send the image and the rest of data from the form to the function in your actions.

Then with axios you have to use like `axios.post(url, formdata)` to send to your database.

Here is my solution with react redux express mongodb.

[how to post image in react-redux using formdata and send to nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52829468/how-to-post-image-in-react-redux-using-formdata-and-send-to-nodejs/68943182#68943182)

Comment: Thanks for your review. Sorry for my english.